# Is there a way to refer two attributes of an object in a list?

Tags: python

I want to know who is the taller athlete (object) in a list of objects. If I want to print it, I tried to write this:

```
print ("The greater height is",max(x.height for x in athletes_list),"meters.")
```

It shows the height of the taller athlete, but I don't know how to get his name by this way, putting all commands in print's body. Is there any way to do this?

I know its possible by creating a for like this:

```
for i in athletes_list:
    if i.height==max(x.height for x in athletes_list):
        print ("The taller athlete is",i.name,"with",i.height,"meters.")
```

Is it possible to get both informations only in print's body?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What if there are more than one athletes with the tallest height?

Comment: You're looking for the argmax. In Python, the way you do this is `max(iterable, key=lambda x: ...)`

Comment: Nice point, @thefourtheye. I'll try to get that solution by myself, using the answers that I found here and a bit of logic. But if someone want to give a way, that would be nice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reread your question.  The answer is still yes.  Use the `format` method of strings:

```
print("The taller athlete is {0.name} with {0.height} meters.".format(max(athletes_list, key=lambda a: a.height)))
```

Comment: Yes, he can also sort the list: `athletes_list.sort(key=lambda a: a.height, reverse=True)` and get the first athlete.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: Of course, if he only wants the first one, the cost of a `sort` is `O(n log n)`, vs. `O(n)` for `max`, so it's only valuable if he actually needs them all sorted.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE plus that mutates the list, which could have ramifications later on

Comment: Yes, agree with you, I only give another solution in comment (this is not an answer).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` over both values (with height first):

```
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get generator based map
from operator import attrgetter

# Ties on height will go to first name alphabetically
maxheight, name = max(map(attrgetter('height', 'name'), athletes))
print("The taller athlete is", name, "with", maxheight, "meters.")
```

Or so ties are resolved by order of appearance, not name:

```
maxheight, name = attrgetter('height', 'name')(max(athletes, key=attrgetter('height')))
```

Comment: Most developer don't really understand `attrgetter`, I prefer using a `lambda` with `max()` like in other answers.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: Most developers don't use `map` correctly either (if you use it with a `lambda`, you're pessimizing, and should just use a listcomp or genexpr instead). I _prefer_ `attrgetter` and `itemgetter` because they are self-documenting and signal "no tricks here". They're also faster, and scale nicely to getting many values at once. I only use `lambda`s when there are tricks (e.g. sort key of `lambda x: x[0], -x[2], x[1]`, note the `-` on `x[2]` that makes `itemgetter(0, 2, 1)` unusable), so when I see `lambda`s in my code, I know to check more carefully. Not worth a downvote though.

Comment: Nice one. Works like charm, but I think this way is a bit more complex than lamba with max() by now.

Comment: @EduardoM: True. The second version's `attrgetter` is pointless; I'd really just store the athlete and use `tallest.height` and `tallest.name` when I'm only looking each one up once. I'm just having fun here. :-)